# Background text in a Flutter list

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a quick alternative to indicate that the list is blank.

Something quick and easy occurs to me that would be to show a text that always says that it is blank... and when the list has an element, said element is placed above the text making it hide.

That is, the text will be behind the list.

Any solution?

My example code is this:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example

```
             StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .where((r) => r.device.name != '')
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this by adding an optional progress loading, if you prefer you can remove it. If your list has items, it will be built, otherwise the text will be displayed.

```
StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
  stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
  initialData: [],
  builder: (c, snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData){
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
    }
    final listItems = snapshot.data!.where((r) => r.device.name != '').toList();
    return  listItems.isNotEmpty ? Column(
        children: snapshot.data!
            .map(
              (r) => ScanResultTile(
                result: r,
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  r.device.connect();
                  return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                })),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        ): const Text("Has no items")
      },
),
```

Comment: Check the code, please. I have **.where((r) => r.device.name != '')** That is, there are always hidden elements without names. A blank list will appear because I hide the unnamed items from the list.

Comment: @principemestizo3 Verify Now